# Latest PHP Framework with ORM in Linux environment which support SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, orm

I've been searching for a **Modern PHP Framework** just like this post's title. I've tried Yii, Laravel, Doctrine, they do not support that (I really like Laravel).

I've been using good ol' [AdoDb PHP DBAL library](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/) for SQL Server in Linux, but combine it with Laravel seems impossible...

Anyway, I'm going to check CodeIgniter, SilverStripe, CakePHP, and Zend Framework (last).

If all fails, then I just go with Laravel and make web-service-interface for SQL Server using NodeJS, but the power of ORM will be gone.

I just need some pointers, suggestion, success stories, or anything...

Thanks

**EDIT01**
Maybe PHP Framework with some kind of technology like Ruby's ActiveResource where the database model is a RESTful web service?

Comment: What do you mean by modern? That it is still being developed? All of the ones you listed are still being actively developed.

Comment: yes, and keep improving. I remembered Doctrine 1.x support SQL server in linux. But in Doctrine 2.x, it just support sqlsrv driver which is Windows only.

Comment: I've never tried to use MSSQL with Yii, but documentation says it does: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao

Comment: yeah, Yii in Windows environment only (not linux)

Comment: CakePHP is the same. MSSQL in Windows environment only. It seems none of the PHP frameworks find supporting MSSQL, or ODBC at all, on Linux a priority. You may have to switch to Ruby/Rails http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/ruby/rails.html